# Indesign: exporting multiple certificates, each with a different name, into separate files

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, export, indesign-scripting, import

I'm looking for efficient way of importing the 1000+ individual names into an InDesign document then exporting out as an individual PDFs (a 1000 page pdf wont work). One name per page.

I have created an InDesign A4 sized certificate that will be used for 1000+ names.

I'm not sure if running a script or ifs there is a batch option already in InDesign that could handle this sort of task.

I have done a certificates before (60+ names). I just made a master page and made the 'name area' editable region. This way I had to copy/paste, export each PDF per name. It took a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to start with InDesign's [Data Merge](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/data-merge.html) feature where you import the list of names from a CSV file, overlay these onto you certificate design and automatically generate a document with 1000+ pages.

Then, to break this into individual files, there is no direct way to do that, but there are some workarounds as described [here](https://indesignsecrets.com/data-merging-individual-records-separate-pdfs.php).

Comment: Since the question specifically says that 1,000 separate PDFs are indeed required, I suggest editing in the steps given on the InDesignSecrets page to make your answer more complete. The way I read it, that's the part Leon is actually having trouble with.

Comment: Did that so i would remove these comments? tnx

Comment: I actually meant it the other way around—adding in the additional steps, not removing the ones that were already there. InDesignSecrets is not particularly likely to go anywhere, but if the link does rot, the answer should really contain the necessary information in itself as well as giving the link.

Comment: Too much to explain really and i would just have to replicate the content from IS. I would assume the OP knows what he's doing and doesn't need a step-by-step guide written down.